# OnClientClick and OnClick relation not working on second hit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

good evening!

I've been trying to use the OnClientClick and OnClick for a validation process. It means, I use the OnClientClick for a confirmation, and proceed with the OnClick if confirmed. The "no" is always ok, we are focusing on the "yes". It all goes well on the first hit, but on the second hit, the PostBack can be seen (it means the "click" was effective), but no action is triggered on code behind.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function testExample(button) {
        var confirmed = confirm("Are you sure?");
        return confirmed;
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btnButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="if(!testExample(this)) return false;" OnClick="btnClicked" Text="Button Test"/>
```

On code behind there is nothing done, just a check if it was triggered:

```
protected void btnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   return;
}
```

Adding or removing`UseSubmitBehavior="false"` does nothing, as also setting `ClientIDMode="Static"` or `AutoID`.

Changing to `OnClientClick="return testExample(this);"` also has no impact. If I do on other buttons individually it happens the same, they all run the first time, the second fails. I am trying to avoid the CssClass and pageLoad() relation.

Can you help me figuring out what I am doing wrong or missing?

EDIT: This seems to happen every time there is a postback event, even after removing `OnClientClick`. This Button is not inside any place holder.

Answer (score 0):

Change your OnClientClick event to

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"
```

Comment: I tried that before, it doesn't work either. The confirm returns "true" or "false", and that has the same behavior as the function used, because the page is indeed refreshed, meaning a postpack, meaning a successful click. It loses the OnClick on the server side.